# I need to GROUP BY, LIMIT, ORDER BY, SUM etc.. on a set of a data that is dynamically created on the fly and will have different columns each time

Tags: mysql, nosql

So basically a User may request multiple `Project` records. The fields that make up the business object `Project` come from various places, some are simply from the `project` table in MySql, some are stored in other tables which I can `join` on to form the record set.

But some values are calculated (and will be calculated every time they request the data - no caching). These may take some time to calculate so I have background processes that calculate these and store them in a `results` table.

Once this is done I want to take all the data and put into a table with the correct columns (different `projects` have different columns based on the User specific setup and also the fields they requested in that particular request) so I can use GROUP BY, LIMIT, ORDER BY, SUM etc.. as if the data was stored as a flat table - I will give the columns the correct data types for example so date ordering works.

Any tables I create will only be used for that one transaction - let's say they are CSV exporting the data. If they CSV export again I will do this whole process again and a new table will be created.

Number of rows per table will be between 1 and 100,000.

**TLDR;**

**Can I rapidly create and destory tables in MySql without any weird issues? Is a NoSql database better for this? Is there another tech that is better for this?**

Comment: Will `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` do?

Comment: Do they only exist for the lifetime of the DB transaction? I'll need the data for longer than that e.g. pagination on a grid

Answer (score 0):

It seams you could use pseudo-temporary tables. `CREATE TABLE temp.csv_data_1234(...),` where `1234` is a user id, or what have you. After you are done with this table you can delete it. There is `pt-find` utility from Percona Toolkit that makes it easy to find and delete those kind of tables.

Comment: Thanks. If I have a lot of Users using the system will MySql have any "weird" issues creating and dropping tables at high frequencies? It just doesn't seem like MySql is built for that so I don't want to hit some weird locking issue at scale.